# How to migrate existing table in sqlite to room database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, migration, android-room

I am trying to migrate my existing data in sqlite to room database.

I have provided a migration rule .

```
This is the migration rule:
private  static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
           database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  temp_account (\n"+
                    " _id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,"
                    + "name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
                    +  "number TEXT DEFAULT 0, "
                    +  "balance REAL DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "
                    +  "account_type TEXT);");

            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp_account( name,number,balance,account_type) " +
                    "SELECT  name,number,balance,account_type FROM account");

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE account");

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE temp_account RENAME TO account;");
;
Below is my original table which I want to migrate:
"CREATE TABLE  account (\n"+
                    " _id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                    + "name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
                    +  "number TEXT DEFAULT 0, "
                    +  "balance REAL , "
                    +  "account_type TEXT);");
```

While it worked in most of the devices but the app crashes in few devices.Crashes are not specific to any device or android version.Below is error report from Google:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:245)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that some of the **balance**s in the original table are **NULL** and when inserting that the newly added **NOT NULL** constraint is in conflict.

You can overcome this by replacing **balance** with either

- `CASE WHEN balance IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE balance END`, or
- `coalesce(balance,0)`

Both will effectively use a value of 0 instead of NULL.

e.g.

```
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp_account( name,number,balance,account_type) " +
                "SELECT  name,number,
                    coalesce(balance,0),
                    account_type FROM account");
```

or

```
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp_account( name,number,balance,account_type) " +
                "SELECT  name,number,
                    CASE WHEN balance IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE balance END,
                    account_type FROM account");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I had to set balance not null in new table as room was not allowing me to have a real type column as non null.But I in my original database I had made sure that a value is inserted in balance column so that value is never null.Also do I have do copy id also from old to new table or autoincrement will generate id by itself.

Comment: @ANKIT you can have a real column as null, BUT the entity must not be a java primary type but an object. i.e. `double mycolumn;` requires not null in the table (even without @NonNull) BUT `Double mycolumn;` can be null (if @NonNull is not coded). You only need to copy the id, if the id is referenced by another table (safest to copy).

Comment: I have checked and your suggestions are working fine on my testing devices.But as my app is live in play store I will release the new version to my testers and wait for their response.One more question what if I don't copy Balance from old to new table.i.e. if I write database.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp_account( name,number,account_type) " +
                "SELECT  name,number,
                                     account_type FROM account"); Will the migaration rule  except me to provide a value for this non null column and throw an error.

Comment: @ANKIT That should work as the default value would come into play and set the balance for all rows to 0. The checking that made you specify NOT NULL (the migration failed expected...../found....) is a comparison of the schema as generated from the Entities against the schema of the table. The Entities rule as such.

Comment: Means if I don't copy balance values then default value of 0 will be set and I won't get any errors.

Comment: @ANKIT I'm pretty sure yes, as basically that's what the answer does except only for the rows where the balance is currently null.

Comment: You mean where balance is currently non null.Because in answer if balance is null then 0 will be set otherwise balance value will be set(First non null value from the method).Am I right?

Comment: Using answer if balance is not null then balance value will be inserted as it is, if the balance is null then the copied row will be 0. If not using the balance when inserting then as no value has been specified the default value of 0 is inserted. In short either way is OK.

Comment: Now I understood.Thanks for the clarification you have been a great help to me.I am truly grateful.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution did not work as one of the testers has reported the same error.This is my code:  database.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp_account(_id,name,number,balance,account_type) " + "SELECT _id,name,number,coalesce(balance,0) ,account_type FROM account"); This is the error:Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException
UNIQUE constraint failed: temp_account._id (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY),.But in my table I have not set _id as Unique.This is entitiy in room:  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  @ColumnInfo(name = "_id") @NonNull   private int _id;

Comment: _id is implicitly unique as it's an alias of the rowid (i.e. INTEGER PRIMARY KEY defines a column as an alias of the rowid) autogenerate = true basically makes it that.

Comment: Then what could be the cause of the problem.Why is app crashing on few devices(10-12 reports)and works successfully on others(around 15000).I have set   android:allowBackup="true "in my manifest,could this be the reason.

Comment: @ Ankit I can't think how as temp_account must be created otherwise it would fail if it existed. As such it would appear that the duplicate id must come from the original table but it can't be as according to your code that's an alias of the rowid and therefore UNIQUE, it's as if you are trying to load the data a second time.

Comment: Yes,from the error report it seems that data is loading the second time.But I am just migrating the data from sqlite to room and have increased the version also.I am also confused from where this duplicate id or table has come.If I use INSERT OR REPLACE instead of just INSERT will it solve the problem.i.e.database.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO temp_account(_id,name,number,balance,account_type) " + "SELECT _id,name,number,coalesce(balance,0) ,account_type FROM account");

Comment: @ANKIT I'd suggest that getting to the bottom of the cause would be the way to go rather than cicrumventing the issue which may hide something that rears it's head later with more severe consequences.

Comment: But I am not sure what is the cause of the problem and if there is anything wrong in the codes then how is it working on other devices and only few devices(less than 5%)are reporting errors.Most of the problem are from Huwaei devices,but other devices have also faced problems.

Comment: You need to find the cause by whittling away e.g. running something like `SELECT * FROM account GROUP BY _id HAVING count() > 1;`. Does it output anything if so then you have duplicate id's in the account table. If so how why? etc. If not then create a table to log last id and count of inserts (init with 1 row), then create a BEFORE INSERT trigger that updates the log table, run and that should pinpoint the duplicate as it should update the log table before the insert.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But the problem is that app is running fine in all of my testing devices and emulators so  test result may not be accurate on my devices .The devices with problems are with users so I can not test on them.Is it possible that in my app users can take backup and store their data in their google drive and when they uninstall and reinstall or open the app in new device the same file is imported.Or is it possible that since autobackup is enabled in my app manifest users device has saved a copy of database and hence duplicate database.

Comment: I have checked in my devices using the raw query method and could not find any duplicate.But I noticed that I have defined id column in original table as   public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID; but in my temp_account table I have defined row id column as _id  and also while copying data I am writing _id instead of BaseColumn._ID. i.e..database.execSQL("INSERT INTO temp_account(_id,name,number,balance,account_type) " + "SELECT _id,name,number,coalesce(balance,0) ,account_type FROM account"); could this be the reason for unique constraint violation.

Comment: What if I don't copy id and let it be auto generated.

Comment: @ANKIT then a unique value would be assigned for each (likely 1 then 2 then 3 etc). However, that would only be safe if other table columns do not reference the id and if that is the case is impossible to say given the available information.

Comment: Yesterday Google showed me more details about the crash and I found out that crash was happening also when I was trying to format the balance in currency according to user's country.So,I fixed that code and released beta version without copying the id as other tables in database do not reference the id.It seems to have fixed the problem for some users and I am still waiting for more feedback from beta testers before releasing the app to production.

Comment: Received no more complaints.It seems the problem was in formatting the balance rather than in migration.